# Inappropriate application of 'good, on topic'

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide?rq=1) is locked because "it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site". The 370k views and 800+ upvotes suggest otherwise.

While rules are useful for asserting the general mechanisms and formulae by which the site should be used, when an exception is deemed useful and relevant by massive community feedback it only makes sense for that to trump "the rules"--rules are for support and structure: to both guarantee what behaviour will *not* be subject to moderator action, and to give the moderators a voice of authority when they are required to take action; their purpose cannot intelligently be construed to effect strangulation of initiative or to facilitate mindless pedantry.

Unless one's goal is a monomanic obsession with adherence to rules above any actual consideration of utility, of course.

At the very outside, a moderator might sensibly have reorganised the formatting into one gigantic post and so forth, although I am not sure if that would actually have been beneficial or not, given that the author used the individual "answers" as a form of anchoring for different sections. While this sort of thing is rarely useful, it's profoundly counter-productive to enforce the rules when doing so results in a net loss of utility.

**Edit:**

Since the point is apparently not sufficiently clear, I am advocating the position that the existing rules are okay as-is, but any and all rules should hinge on the principle of least-enforcement: that is, rules exist to give mods a way to deal with problematic, useless, counter-productive, or otherwise damaging behaviour/material--but even if something breaks the rules in a technical sense, if leaving it as-is results in a net gain (in terms of utility, in this case, a well organised collection of useful information) then it ought to be left well enough alone.

The worst-case result from following this policy is that more useful information is accumulated in a way which runs counter to the particular format described by the rules, but so long as that information is contributing to the overall usefulness of the site in question, I can hardly see how that qualifies as a problem that must be remedied.

Comment: If there were such adherence, that question would have been deleted.

Comment: @Oded That would only have been a more extreme form of taking action; my point is that no action of any sort was truly warranted.

Comment: This kind of lock is **only** for very popular questions

Comment: I disagree. If the community has, over time, changed its ideas about what is and is not acceptable, but still wants to retain some history and some great content that doesn't conform to the new way of doing things, this is a good compromise (while telling new comers that standards have changed).

Comment: @RichardTingle I have seen locking effected to prevent "me too" or "thanks" spam, but that isn't the reason given.

Comment: Also the rules are discussed and decided here. If you want to change them propose a change here.  It was the rules decided here under which the question was locked

Comment: @Vector thats protected not locked. But different kinds of lock exist. **This kind** is solely for popular, off topic questions

Comment: @RichardTingle Noted; however, my long experience with group mechanics suggests that "more rules" is rarely the solution to any problem of any sort.

Comment: This seems like an entirely sensible historical lock - there *is* valuable information, which is preserved, but it isn't exactly Q&A as we know it. There might be 50+ topical questions nested away there, not **a** topical question.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth If you have another solution that you feel would more effectively address a given problem than what current policy dictates, then by all means, propose a change here on meta.  If your proposal is that this question should just be on topic and allowable, I doubt you'll see much traction.  That's been tried many, many times.  A lot of discussion has gone into deciding that questions like these are off topic.  If you have a better way of dealing with such offtopic questions than locking them though, we're more than willing to listen to your proposal.

Comment: @Servy There is a specific policy change embedded in the question; would you like me to go back and clarify?

Comment: *"The 370k views and 800+ upvotes suggest otherwise."* No it really doesn't. That means it's popular. And that doesn't imply it's on-topic .

Comment: @Bart Then why permit upvoting at all? Your comment undermines the idea of upvotes being used to record the usefulness of a question or answer.

Comment: @Flexo That is more or less the entirety of my point: there IS useful information there, but it isn't Q&A. So what? It's still making the site better, by adding to the net sum of knowledge contained therein; I hardly apprehend that to be problematic; even if it were duplicated in kind, so what? The site becomes more useful? How is that a problem?

Comment: I do not argue that there is no value there. I do not argue that there isn't something there that is liked. But SO is narrowly scoped. There is tons of possible content that I'd love to read, but that isn't good for the site itself.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth In reality, votes tend to really *mean* popularity, especially on questions with that much traffic.  We use this as an approximation of usefulness, even though it's an imperfect approximation.  Neither popularity nor usefulness is *any* indication of, or even approximation of, on-topic-ness.

Comment: @Bart How is it "not good for the site itself"? Please clarify this position.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth `"There is a specific policy change embedded in the question; would you like me to go back and clarify?"` My understanding of your proposal was to simply pretend that this question is on topic and allow it.  Your edit further enforces this belief.  As I said earlier, the community has spend *considerable* time discussing whether questions like these should be on topic.  A decision has been made that they shouldn't be.  People have further proposed exceptions for certain questions, like these.  It has been shown that having those exceptions is harmful.

Comment: @Servy Topical relevance isn't as important, in my opinion, as utility and informativeness. The popularity suggests it was both useful and informative; whether or not it was "relevant" is not an issue--unless *Exchange gets so choked with "useful but off topic stuff" that it threatens to completely swamp the ordinary Q&A function, but I cannot frankly imagine that occurring, so long as the rules continue to discourage the practise. It is not often that the opportunity comes along for something to be at once so "off topic" and so useful at the same time.

Comment: The site is a Q&A. Question and Answer. I don't think we have to debate about the fact that it's not a question. There are tons of them there. And external references. And the answers don't answer a single question. They answer tons of them. That doesn't adhere to the format of the site, and sets a bad example for others if left open. The content is arguably valuable, that's what it's still around. But it's overall not what we expect of a question and answer.

Comment: @Servy So you think that enforcing the informational structure of a site is more important than cultivating overall utility? I didn't say "pretend it's on topic"--I said, flatly acknowledge that it breaks the rules and it's still useful so leave it be. Rules are supposed to be a guide, not a religion.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth "I said, flatly acknowledge that it breaks the rules and it's still useful so leave it be." is that not what we are doing by locking it instead of closing it? if left unlocked, it's likely that people will in the future find it and close it as off topic, thus losing all of this useful information due to rules changing over time.

Comment: In regard to your edit/addendum - locking the question means that it cannot gain more answers - gaining more answers would be **actively harmful** to the community. It is also damaging to not show the notice as otherwise other people can point to the post as "but why is this one OK and mine not?" - the lock and notice serve a purpose and are the minimal intervention you speak of.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth `"Topical relevance isn't as important, in my opinion, as utility and informativeness."` That's because you're looking very narrowly at a single question and not considering the widespread implications of your proposal.  For every useful question of this form there are *thousands and thousand* of unuseful questions proposed.  When you start allowing exceptions everyone thinks that their awful question is worthy of an exception and decides to post it, and then argue against its closure, using questions such as this one as an example of why they should be allowed to post their.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth `"I said, flatly acknowledge that it breaks the rules and it's still useful so leave it be."`  Which is exactly what the lock does.  It indicates to all readers that the question is not acceptable on the site, that you shouldn't attempt to ask similar questions, but it still leaves the useful information there for people to use it.  How is that not exactly what you want?

Comment: @Servy Yes, but their questions are awful. If they complain, who cares? Hell, make it into a rule, if you will: "We *might* allow exceptions for very highly rated questions. If yours isn't very highly rated, don't expect us to give you a break."

Comment: @Oded given that I'm not 10k, any insight in the amount of deleted answers on that question?

Comment: @VectorGorgoth Because they flood the site with crap.  The consume a considerable amount of moderation effort to remove the questions, explain why their question isn't allowed, explain why they aren't worthy of an exception, console the user so they don't get pissed off (even though they usually will anyway), etc.  All of that time could be better spend providing quality answers to questions instead.

Comment: @Servy That's why this is a 'discussion' instead of a complaint--perhaps you're right. I don't know. I would tend to think that some other tag-- "Archived for posterity" or some-such-- would better communicate what you just said.

Comment: @Bart there's just the one deleted answer

Comment: @Bart - but 37 that are not. And That's probably 30 answers more than we want.

Comment: I agree that "archived" might be a better choice of words than "locked". There's been misunderstandings of the "locked" state before.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth That is, for all intents and purposes, exactly what a "historical lock" is, except that since it's not a tag, but it's own special feature with a big banner and all of that gives it quite a lot more authority than just a tag.

Comment: @Oded Yep, but admittedly I would have expected it to attract more crap.

Comment: @Servy I suspect they'd do that anyway. Stupid users are an invariant, and they WILL bitch about anything and everything, no matter what you do. So just don't try to placate them. Delete their crap and ignore their whining. If they really have a point, they'll make an intelligent discussion on Meta and prove us wrong in assuming the were stupid.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth 1) That's a good way to lose users from your site; deleting their stuff without even explaining why. 2) It's much more understandable for them to be asking such questions when you actually do allow some of them.  They actually have reasonable reason to think they might be allowed.  By not having exceptions and not allowing questions like this, you prevent a *lot* of people from asking questions like this in the first place, again, greatly reducing the moderation effort (as there are no questions to close/delete), not pissing of users, etc.

Comment: @Servy Well, I wouldn't say "never explain", but stick it in an FAQ and link it to them or some-such. Make it automatic when you delete, that the reason causes them to get a message with a link to the appropriate item. And it's only reasonable if your question is very like the other question--that is, has all of the other attributes, in terms of utility, thoroughness, depth, etc. in addition to merely being off-topic. But I'll defer to your superior expertise.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth We do automatically do all of that when closing questions.  However, to avoid a gigantic list of close reasons that would make closing questions *very* hard, the close reasons need to be generalized such that there are only a handful of them.  This means that some users aren't able to understand how the more generalized reason applies to their case, and as a result, it's frequently necessary for close reasons to be further clarified in comments by users.

Comment: @Servy I would argue, myself, that such users can never possibly contribute anything of worth to the site, especially to the more formal Exchanges. Accommodating idiocy is veritably sure to cultivate popularity, but as we've established popularity is not strictly a measure of utility.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth Determining what is on and offtopic is both complicated, and subjective.  That someone doesn't understand immediately why a given question is offtopic in no way makes them an idiot, nor does it mean they will never have anything to contribute.  By that logic, given that you couldn't even understand the purpose of a historical lock you are an idiot and will never have anything of worth to contribute to this site.

Comment: I understood the purpose; I argued it was mis-applied. Even locking it with an 'archival' tag would still not necessarily be correct, in my mind, though it would better describe the reasoning behind doing so.

Comment: "Unless one's goal is a monomanic obsession with adherence to rules above any actual consideration of utility, of course." Best description of Stack Overflow ever? I want to make that the core of my platform when I run in the moderator elections.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The site is a Q&A. Question and Answer. I don't think we have to debate about the fact that it's not a question. There are tons of them there. And external references. And the answers don't answer a single question. They answer a lot of them.

That doesn't adhere to the format of the site, which is very straight forward. You ask one question, and all the answers below it answer that one question. The post sets a bad example for others if left open. The content is arguably valuable, that's what it's still around. But it's overall not what we expect of a question and answer.

> if leaving it as-is results in a net gain (in terms of utility, in this case, a well organised collection of useful information) then it ought to be left well enough alone.

And that is exactly what the lock achieves, up to a point. It acknowledges the fact that the content is valuable. It doesn't harm that in any way.

> The worst-case result from following this policy is that more useful information is accumulated in a way which runs counter to the particular format described by the rules

It is precisely this "running counter to the particular format" that is a problem. Q&A is clear and simple. Q&Q&Q&Q&Resource&Q&A&A&A&A&link&A not so much. Locking will stop this ball of content from gaining even more mass over time, which will no doubt not improve its clarity and might even harm its usefulness.

Additionally you do want to send a signal to others saying "listen, this might still be around, but you can't get away with that any more". You want to avoid the whole "why did you close my question if that one is okay?" scenario.

So in this case the lock is the best thing that could have happened. Great valuable content that's here to stay, at a point where it's still mostly valuable content.

Comment: Even if I disagree with you, it answers the "question".

Comment: Ha, you don't have to accept the answer if you don't want @VectorGorgoth. By all means leave it open so it might attract other answers (Though you're free to switch acceptance if others do answer later). I'm only one voice (sometimes of reason). Others might contribute different viewpoints.

Comment: I suspect your position is the one which will prevail, and it explains it well. I don't have to agree with it to accept that it's how things are around here.

Comment: Fair enough. Don't hesitate though.

Comment: Do I come off as a particularly hesitant person? Perish the thought.